# Order of evaluation of elements in list-initialization

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, initializer-list, operator-precedence

In the [other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056000/how-to-avoid-undefined-execution-order-for-the-constructors-when-using-stdmake), @Dietmar gave this solution:

```
template <typename... T>
std::tuple<T...> parse(std::istream& in) 
{
    return std::tuple<T...>{ T(in)... };
}
```

stating that,

> The use of brace initialization works because the **order of evaluation of the arguments** in a brace initializer list **is the order in which they appear**. (emphasize mine)

The relevant text from the C++ Standard (n3485) is,

> Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack expansions (14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear. That is, every value computation and side effect associated with a given initializer-clause is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with any initializer-clause that follows it in the comma-separated list of the initializer-list. 
>   [ Note: This evaluation ordering holds regardless of the semantics of the initialization; for example, it applies when the elements of the initializer-list are interpreted as arguments of a constructor call, even though ordinarily there are no sequencing constraints on the arguments of a call. —end note ]

---

So I tried to test this with the following code:

```
template<int N>
struct A 
{ 
    std::string data;
    A(std::istream & stream) { stream >> data; }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & out, A<N> const & a) 
    {
        return out << "A"<<N<<"::data = " << a.data;
    }
};
typedef A<1> A1;
typedef A<2> A2;

template<typename ...Args>
void test(std::istream & stream)
{
    std::tuple<Args...> args { Args(stream)... };
    std::cout << std::get<0>(args) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<1>(args) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss("A1 A2");
    test<A1,A2>(ss);
}
```

Expected output:

```
A1::data = A1
A2::data = A2
```

Actual Output:

```
A1::data = A2
A2::data = A1
```

Did I do anything wrong in my test code? I changed my code to this:

```
std::stringstream ss("A1 A2");
std::tuple<A1,A2> args{A1(ss), A2(ss)};
std::cout << std::get<0>(args) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::get<1>(args) << std::endl
```

Same output as before. I tested my code with `MinGW (GCC) 4.7.0` and `4.7.2`. Even ideone gives [this output](http://ideone.com/jPrpiR).

Is it a bug in the compiler?

Comment: clang-3.2 generates the expected output.  Maybe it's a gcc bug?

Comment: This is a GCC bug. Clang gets it correct.

Comment: What are you expecting us to aswer? "Yes it is a bug because of the quote you are giving". Hasn't this been said twice today? Both in the question by @Dietmar and in the question Dietmar references, quotes and examples were given that state that the order is left to right.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I'm just making sure that is a bug in the compiler and that there is absolutely nothing wrong with my test code.

Comment: I'd also check back before going through the bug reporting procedure at gcc.

Comment: Has anybody reported this bug to GCC? or shall I?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<sup>Answering my own question. Deleting the question would not be a good idea, as someone might have the same question in the future.</sup>

Yes. It is a bug in the GCC compiler.

- [Bug 51253 - [C++11][DR 1030] Evaluation order (sequenced-before relation) among initializer-clauses in braced-init-list](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253)

taken from @Johannes Schaub's comment to the question.

Comment: Note that Microsoft's Visual Studio 12 (2013) has the same bug, which I just reported at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/976911/braced-initializer-list-not-evaluated-left-to-right

Comment: This will be fixed in MSVC 2015 Update 2 (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/11/compiler-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-2/)