# ordering of function calls in initializer list

Tags: c++11, initialization

I'm wondering about the execution order of function calls given in an initializer list:

```
#include <iostream>

class ExpandWithConstructor
{
    public:
        template < typename ... T>
            ExpandWithConstructor( T... args) {}
};

    template < typename T>
T Print( T t )
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    ExpandWithConstructor{ Print(1.1),Print("Hallo"),Print('c')};
}
```

Executing the code gives:

```
c
Hallo
1.1
```

Q: Is the reverse order of functions defined in the standard or is there no guarantee for the ordering?

I use g++ 4.8.1.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060264/order-of-evaluation-of-elements-in-list-initialization and http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253

Comment: Thanks! Yes, your link exactly answer what I ask for!

Comment: TLDR: Yes it's defined, no it's not reverse order, [GCC has a bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253).