# Why does an explicit move after use in braced initializer list break the return value?

Tags: c++, return, move, braced-init-list

I had a problem that appeared in GCC and Clang, but not MSVC. The problematic part boils down to this:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

auto mkStrings() -> std::pair<std::string, std::string>
{
    std::string r = "r";
    return { r, "s" + std::move(r) }; // !
}

int main()
{
    auto [r, s] = mkStrings();
    std::cout << "'" << r << " " << s << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

On MSVC, I get:

```
'r sr'
```

On GCC 12.2.0 and Clang 15.0.7, it outputs:

```
' sr'
```

(On Clang 16.0.1 the compiler segfaults.)

I’m quite convinced the `std::move` is a problem, but I don’t understand why. I even looked up if I was mistaken that initializer lists are evaluated left-to-right, but according to [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852367/are-there-sequence-points-in-braced-initializer-lists-when-they-apply-to-constru) they are.

Of course, I just removed the `std::move`, but I’d like to understand why I had to.

Comment: In general with most C++ standard library objects, since you **move** an object, it is left behind in a valid-but-unspecified state (suitable for destruction, or reassignment).  (Some classes have additional guarantees, like `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`.)  I think there are no guarantees which side of the `{ a, b }` arguments are evaluated first (it's an implementation detail).  Oh the details are confusing, [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list%20initialization).  Ow, my brain.

Comment: `pair(_T1 const& __t1, _T2 const& __t2)` ... looks like the constructor is getting the rug pulled out from under it, because it's a const-ref to the parameters.  But the `move` in the second argument is gutting the `r` before the constructor sees the `__t1`.

Comment: I'm guessing that Microsoft's STL doesn't bother "emptying" a moved-from string if SSO is in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following constructor is used for the initialization:

```
template <class U1, class U2>
constexpr pair(U1&& x, U2&& y);
```

(In C++23, default template arguments will be added, but this doesn't affect the answer.)

Because you're using braced initialization, the parameter `x` will be initialized before the parameter `y`. However both `x` and `y` must be initialized before the *ctor-initializer* can be evaluated (which actually initializes the `first` and `second` members).

So `x` is first bound to `r`, then `y` to the temporary result of the expression `"s" + std::move(r)`. At this point, `r` may be moved from.

Afterward, the constructor uses `std::forward<U1>(x)` to initialize `first`. But at this point, the move from the object that `x` refers to has already been performed.

Answer (score 0):

Because the order of the evaluation inside a braced initializer is unspecified. GCC and Clang seem to evaluate `"s" + std::move(r)` first, after that `r` is empty.

[Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

> 21) Every expression in a comma-separated list of expressions in a parenthesized initializer is evaluated as if for a function call (indeterminately-sequenced)

Comment: The OP isn't using a parenthesized initializer.  They are using list initialization which has: *In list-initialization, every value computation and side effect of a given initializer clause is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with any initializer clause that follows it in the brace-enclosed comma-separated list of initializers.*

Comment: @NathanOliver If you look at [Direct-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), you see that Direct-list-initialization is initialization of a named variable with a *braced-init-list*.

Comment: Yeah, *braced*, not *parenthesized*.  A parenthesized initializer is `T(foo)`, not `T{foo}`.

Comment: Got it, I misread it. Will look for a proper reference.