# Tuple isn't being constructed in order?

Tags: c++, constructor, stdtuple

The following [program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cec8734b09c0cf24):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct A {
    A() { std::cout << "A constructor\n"; }
};

struct B {
    B() { std::cout << "B constructor\n"; }
};

int main() {
    std::tuple<A, B> t;
}
```

gives different outputs on different compilers:

```
# libstdc++
B constructor
A constructor
# libc++
A constructor
B constructor
```

This seem weird... I figured the standard would have guaranteed the tuple elements be constructed in-order, e.g., A, B, ..., Y, Z?

Comment: Hmm, but regardless the X constructor was being called before A, you're saying it's because I'm using get?

Comment: This behavior would make sense if the selected constructor is `std::tuple<A,X>::tuple(const A&, const X&)` (since function arguments are unordered), but I would think the selected constructor should actually be `template<class... U> std::tuple<A,X>::tuple(U&&...)`.

Comment: It's hard to say, but I feel like it should be okay using `get`. The element wouldn't be initialized, but all `get` would do is return a reference, which then has its address taken, resulting in no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. However, accessing `y` on that pointer might not be.

Comment: @Matt Well that doesn't compile since it won't let me reference the uninitialized type tup, but I'll try to reorganize the code within the next few minutes.

Comment: A much shorter example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/271c3ba0b6240f8f

Comment: @asch oh whoops I see what you're saying now.  I'll put the get in a seperate question later, then.

Comment: Depending of standard library, result differs: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/764d0477523ba249).

Comment: So it should depend of implementation of tuple, if element are in order or in reverse order.

Comment: @Jarod well okay, so I must have been wrong about it being in the standard.  I guess I'll have to put up a request to get ordered construction standardized.

Comment: I would call this unspecified behavior, not undefined.  I also checked the Standard but didn't see anything implying an order of construction.

Comment: @aschepler in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14057064/1505939) Dietmar Kuhl claims the order is well-defined (but does not provide references)

Comment: It looks like he changed his mind in the comments discussion under that answer, though.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that the committee would mandate an order of construction. A common implementation based on recursive inheritance, for instance, causes construction to happen in reverse order.

Comment: @T.C. Well I don't know much about how the committee would decide on things like this, but I'd argue: a tuple is essentially a type-generic struct, and it should act like one.  If it's possible to construct the elements in order (which has been shown to be possible), it should construct the elements in order, so as to match a struct's behavior.

Comment: `std::pair` mandates a construction order as its constructors are defined as operating on the `first` and `second` members, which are in turn defined in order. There's no such requirement for `std::tuple` however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::tuple` construction order is currently [unspecified](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/764d0477523ba249).

A proposal for a concrete decision on its order has been [submitted](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2528) to the committee but until then the order should not be relied on.

Answer (score 2):

As you've seen, the standard does not define an ordering here.  I've only seen it happen in reverse order, but in principle a compiler could do anything it wanted.  Worse, your request for a "standardized constructor" will not prosper, because this issue isn't specific to constructors: all function arguments work this way!

Consider this example:

```
bool putOnTheSpaceSuits() { /* ... */ }
bool openTheAirlock() { /* ... */ }
void tryGoIntoSpace(bool spaceSuitsOn, bool airlockOpen) {
  if(spaceSuitsOn && airlockOpen) {
    spacewalk();
  }
}
```

What happens when we run `tryGoIntoSpace(putOnTheSpaceSuits(), openTheAirlock())`?  On my machine, `openTheAirlock()` is evaluated first, dumping our unprotected astronauts into space.  Oops!

Your original question uses two implicit conversions; it's equivalent to `std::tuple<X,Y> t(X(1),Y(2));`.  You can see the same effect with any random free function that takes an `X` and a `Y`:

```
void frob(X x, Y y) { /* ... */ }

frob(X(1), Y(2)); // It's unspecified, but I bet Y(2) will happen first here.
```

See for yourself: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4142f3c8342ebf2

The fact that you're using a recursively-templated tuple constructor isn't relevant here; all C++ functions are alike.  Ideally your function arguments should not have interesting, mutually-interacting side effects, but if that's impossible, you have to do the ordering yourself:

```
X x(1);
Y y(2);
std::tuple<X,Y> t(x, y);
```

Comment: You can move `x` and `y` inside `t` to achieve the same semantics.

Comment: In general yes, though in this case `t` is a library function.

Comment: BTW, it is not a problem with (undefined) function ordering call in OP code, `std::tuple<X, Y>(1, 2)` is not *equivalent* to `std::tuple<X, Y>(X(1), Y(2))` as `X`, `Y` are built in place and not moved from the temporaries. it is actually the difference between `struct tup {tup(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {} X x; Y y;};` and `struct tup {tup(int a, int b) : y(b), x(a) {} Y y; X x;};`.

Comment: Construction and function calls are fundamentally different, you shouldn't really compare the two.  We rely on a struct's promise that its elements are constructed in the order they are declared in, for example, because this gives us the ability to pass in refs to the elements to others later down the chain.  Since tuples are essentially type generic structs, there is no reason for them to vary this implementation.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez I'm not sure what to tell you except that the standard doesn't agree.  If you want to control the order in which the constructors are called, you have to move the calls into the tuple constructor, as proposed by Jarod42 or Quentin.

Comment: @David Well I've submitted an [issue to the standard](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2528), all we can do now is wait for a fix unfortunately

Comment: @BrianRodriguez: And they didn't vary this implementation. The thing you want to rely on that you currently can't is that the order of declaration of the members. Think `struct tuple<A,B...> : private tuple<B...> { A data; };`

Comment: @Hurkyl There are tuple implementations that don't rely on recursion, see some of the posts [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/mbD5G5mqKwE).  Thus right now, it's just a matter of getting the committee to decide whether it's worth standardizing an implementation, and I've put in an argument for standardizing in-order.