# C++ multiple forwarding of one reference: first copy and then move

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-precedence, stdtuple, list-initialization

Consider the following code, where the same reference is forwarded two times to a base class and used there to construct a tuple:

```
template<typename ... Ts>
struct Base
{
    template<typename ... _Ts>
    Base(_Ts&& ... ts) : tup{std::forward<_Ts>(ts) ...} {}

    std::tuple <Ts ...> tup;
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T, T>
{
    template<typename _T>
    Derived(_T&& t) : Base<T, T>{t, std::forward<_T>(t)} {}
};
```

Calling first the base class constructor in `Derived` as `Base<T, T>{t, std::forward<_T>(t)}` and thereafter also the tuple constructor using `tup{std::forward<Ts>(ts)...}` has the following reason:

When `t` is an rvalue reference, the first tuple argument shall be passed an lvalue-ref to `t` and thus be constructed through a copy of `t`, whereas the second tuple element should get an rvalue-ref and therefore, if possible, use a move for construction.

This approach seems to be supported by several questions and answers on SO (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14058592/2412846), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14057064/2412846) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21234522/2412846)) which state that the braced-init list performs to a left-to-right evaluation of its arguments.

However, when I use the above code in a simple example, the actual behavior is (consistently) the opposite of what I expected:

```
struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(A const& other) : vec(other.vec) { std::cout<<"copy"<<std::endl; }
    A(A && other) : vec(std::move(other.vec)) { std::cout<<"move"<<std::endl; }

    std::vector<int> vec = std::vector<int>(100);
};

int main()
{
    Derived<A> d(A{});  //prints first "move", then "copy"

    std::cout<<std::get<0>(d.tup).vec.size()<<std::endl;  //prints 0
    std::cout<<std::get<1>(d.tup).vec.size()<<std::endl;  //prints 100
}
```

Here is [the example using gcc on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45bb1720ad53dae1). (The gcc compiler apparently had a bug once in this connection, but it's about two years since and should be no issue anymore.)

Questions:

- Where am I wrong on the implementation or the assumptions here?
- How can the above code be fixed to behave as expected: first copy -- then move?

Comment: any symbol beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved for the implementation; change `_T` and `_Ts` to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the order-of-operations on the object initializations matter. Due to the perfect forwarding, no copies or moves are actually made (i.e. only lvalue references and rvalue references are passed around) until the `std::tuple` constructor is called. And, at that point, it depends on the implementation details of `std::tuple`.

Consider if instead of `std::tuple` you used the following `my_tup` struct:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct my_tup
{
    template <typename A, typename B>
    my_tup(A&& a, B&& b) 
        : t1(std::forward<A>(a)), t2(std::forward<B>(b))
    {
    }

    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
};
```

This prints, as expected, "copy" and then "move" ([coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2700306f149986ff)). But if instead you have:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct my_tup
{
    template <typename A, typename B>
    my_tup(A&& a, B&& b) 
        : t2(std::forward<B>(b)), t1(std::forward<A>(a))
    {
    }

    T2 t2;
    T1 t1;
};
```

Then this prints "move", then "copy", as `std::tuple` does ([coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2f4c56b747436da)).

Likely due to the way the variadic template is expanded, `std::tuple` must be dealing with the arguments in a right-to-left manner. I am not sure whether this is implementation-dependent or specified in the spec.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I guess. Evaluation does not mean construction. And a corresponding tuple construction constraint in the standard does not seem to exist.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192809/tuple-isnt-being-constructed-in-order) which states that there is no standard order in the tuple construction.

Answer (score 2):

You should do the copy explicitly, else you pass a reference which is later used by copy (but, with the alias, may have been moved):

```
template<typename U>
struct Derived : public Base<U, U>
{
    template<typename T>
    Derived(T&& t) : Base<U, U>{T(t), std::forward<T>(t)} {}
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e465a9b4ddf9934)

Comment: Nice trick: This should work (arguments being functions are called before passing  the result to the constructor and std::forward is just a cast)