# Tuple and variadic templates, how does this work?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates

I have seen people write (on stack overflow itself, asking some even advanced concepts) something along the lines of:

```
template<typename... args>
std::tuple<args...> parse(istream stream) 
{
    return std::make_tuple(args(stream)...);
}
```

and use it as

```
auto tup = parse<int, float, char>(stream);
```

How does the above code construct the tuple by parsing the stream? Is there any specific requirement on how data is to be put into the stream?

Comment: Are you referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14033828/873025)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works poorly.  It relies on the target type having a constructor that takes an `std::istream`.

As many types don't have this, and you cannot add it to something like `int`, this is a bad plan.

Instead do this:

```
template<class T>
auto read_from_stream( std::istream& stream, T* unused_type_tag )
-> typename std::decay<decltype( T{stream} )>::type
{
  return {stream};
}
template<class T>
auto read_from_stream( std::istream& stream, T* unused_type_tag, ... )
-> typename std::decay<decltype( T(stream) )>::type
{
  return T(stream);
}

template<typename... args>
std::tuple<args...> parse(std::istream& stream)  {
  return std::tuple<args...>{
    read_from_stream(stream, (args*)nullptr)...
  };
}
```

now instead of directly constructing the arguments, we call `read_from_stream`.

`read_from_stream` has two overloads above.  The first tries to directly and implicitly construct our object from an `istream`.  The second explicitly constructs our object from an `istream`, then uses RVO to return it.  The `...` ensures that the 2nd one is only used if the 1st one fails.

In any case, this opens up a point of customization.  In the namespace of a type `X` we can write a `read_from_stream( std::istream&, X* )` function, and it will automatically be called instead of the default implementation above.  We can also write `read_from_stream( std::istream&, int* )` (etc) which can know how to parse integers from an `istream`.

This kind of point of customization can also be done using a traits class, but doing it with overloads has a number of advantages: you can inject the customizations adjacent to the type, instead of having to open a completely different namespace.  The custom action is also shorter (no class wrapping noise).

Comment: There is a big problem with that implementation, there is no guarantee that the parameters to `make_tuple` are evaluate left to right. This is an unspecified behavior. And in fact, clang and gcc behave the opposite. GCC http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0688e941dfc9c563 and CLANG http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d136ebd8dd32c43d

Comment: Instead of using `std::make_tuple( blabla... )` you have to use `std::tuple<args...> { blabla... }` to enforce the evaluation order ( note the use of {} instead of () ).

Comment: @galop1n *nod*, fixed.  As an aside, find the inability to "directly construct via function" the parts of a tuple annoying: the above requires move-ability of the data, for no good reason.

Comment: @Yakk, I am using vs2013 to use your code and it cries : error C2668: 'read_from_stream' : ambiguous call to overloaded function. Any ideas?

Comment: @arun eliminate first overload, and the `...` in second.  It is only useful in a corner case anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work there must be an implicit conversion from `std::istream` to all the types specified as template arguments.

```
struct A {
    A(std::istream&) {} // A can be constructed from 'std::istream'.
};

struct B {
    B(std::istream&) {} // B can be constructed from 'std::istream'.
};

int main() {
    std::istringstream stream{"t1 t2"};
    auto tup = parse<A, B>(stream);
}
```

It works by expanding the variadic list of types and constructs each type with the supplied `std::istream` as argument. It is then left to the constructor of each type to read from the stream.

Also be aware that the evaluation order of the constructors is not specified so you can't expect that the first type in the variadic list will read from the stream first etc.

The code as it is does *not* work with built in types as `int`, `float` and `char` as there is no conversion from `std::istream` to any of those types.

Comment: Iam on VS2013 and I get the following error
error C2144: syntax error : 'A' should be preceded by ')'