# How I declare a std::tuple using variadic templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Perhaps I being naive here, but I believe the following code should compile:

```
template <typename ... T>
struct Test {
        std::tuple<T> foo;
};

int main() {
        struct Test<int, long> test;

        return 0;
}
```

Instead g++ complains:

```
test.cpp:5: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
test.cpp:5: note:         'T'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please do some [basic research about a feature](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) before asking about it on SO. It's not like the information isn't out there.

Comment: I did, I kept hitting this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033828/translating-a-stdtuple-into-a-template-parameter-pack which wasn't helpful.

Comment: Did you try Google? A simple "C++ use variadic template" search would have found you tons of resources.

Answer (score 1):

You do that by expanding the pack with `...`:

```
template <typename... T>
struct Test
{
    std::tuple<T...> foo;
    //         ^^^^
};
```

Comment: This did it!  Would the same trick work when passing it as a argument?  For example the constructor `Test(T...t) : foo(std::make_tuple(t)) {};` gives me a similar error

Comment: To answer my own question, need to do `t...` in the argument to `make_tuple`.