# How do I create an std::tuple<> from a variadic template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have a class that is declared with this template: `template <typename ...Args>`. In it, I have a list declared as `std::vector<std::tuple<Args...>> vec;` to store data entries specified by the template. I also have a function declared as follows:

```
void AddVertex(Args... data)
{
    // vec.push_back(std::tuple<Args...>(data));
}
```

In this function, I want to add a tuple of Args... to the vector. Is this possible? I have tried using the code in the comment, but the compiler gives me an error saying that "the parameter pack must be expanded in this context".

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34191970/3314466) solution doesn't work, because the template argument of the tuple is already expanded.

Comment: Include the real vector in your function. Obviously it isn't a member variable somewhere. A [mcve] with everything but the push would do nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to expand both:

- template parameters pack (`Args...`)

and

- function parameters pack (`data...`):

so it should be:

```
    vec.push_back(std::tuple<Args...>(data...));
```

---

Or shorter form, use `make_tuple`:

```
    vec.push_back(std::make_tuple(data...));
```

Comment: Thanks, `std::make_tuple` did it!

Comment: `std::make_tuple` is wrong though when `Args` is reference.

Answer (score 3):

As hinted by the compiler, you need to expand the parameter pack `data`, so this should work:

```
void AddVertex(Args... data)
{
    vec.push_back(std::tuple<Args...>(args...));
}
```

Also, consider using `emplace_back` instead:

```
void AddVertex(Args... data)
{
    vec.emplace_back(args...);
}
```

Both of the above functions will copy every argument and thus are not idiomatic C++. This may or may not be an issue to you. To avoid this do something like

```
template <typename... T>
void AddVertex(T&&... args)
{
    vec.emplace_back(std::forward<T>(args)...);
}
```

which is a little more verbose, but will avoid those unnecessary copies.